# Javascript update HTML cells

Tags: javascript, html, cells

I'm new to Javascript and have modified some free code but have become stuck adding an extra bit of functionality... hoping someone can fill in the last gap.

The top table of property sales updates correctly to the 'Total Sales' and automatically to the 'Commission Payable' at the top and bottom of the page, however I have added a 'Costs' table and want the total of those costs to auto populate the 'Total Costs' box at the bottom and have the Commission Payable box auto factor this in...

This is what the page looks like:
http://tinypic.com/r/iqj6dj/8

This is the 'Update Invoice' section of the javascript:

```
/* Update Invoice
/* ========================================================================== */

function updateInvoice() {
var total = 0;
var totalcosts = 0;
var cells, price, total, totalcosts, a, i;

// update inventory cells
// ======================

for (var a = document.querySelectorAll('table.inventory tbody tr'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) {

    // get inventory row cells
    cells = a[i].querySelectorAll('span:last-child');

    // set gross as cell[2] * cell[3]
    gross = parseFloatHTML(cells[1]) * parseFloatHTML(cells[2]) / 100;

    // set gross total
    cells[3].innerHTML = gross;

    // set nett total as gross - gst - franchise
    nett = parseFloatHTML(cells[3]) /11 * 10;

    // set nett total
    cells[4].innerHTML = nett;

    // set split total as 50%
    split50 = parseFloatHTML(cells[4]) / 2;

    // set split total
    cells[5].innerHTML = split50;

    // add price to total
    total += split50;

}

for (var a = document.querySelectorAll('table.costs tbody tr'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) {

    // get inventory row cells
    cells = a[i].querySelectorAll('span:last-child');

    // set costs total
    cells[5].innerHTML = costs;

    // add costs to totalcosts
    totalcosts += costs;

}

// update balance cells
// ====================

// get balance cells
cells = document.querySelectorAll('table.balance td:last-child span:last-child');

// set totalsales
cells[0].innerHTML = total;

// set balance and meta balance
cells[2].innerHTML = document.querySelector('table.meta tr:last-child td:last-child span:last-child').innerHTML = parsePrice(total - parseFloatHTML(cells[1]));

// update prefix formatting
// ========================

var prefix = document.querySelector('#prefix').innerHTML;
for (a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-prefix]'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) a[i].innerHTML = prefix;


// update price formatting
// =======================

for (a = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-prefix] + span'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) if (document.activeElement != a[i]) a[i].innerHTML = parsePrice(parseFloatHTML(a[i]));

}
```

The second variable regarding table.costs breaks the functionality and is obviously done wrong. Any help appreciated.

To answer the comments, sorry for not providing the HTML in the first place, it is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="license" href="http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license/">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Invoice</h1>
        <address contenteditable>
            <p>Company Name</p>
        </address>
        <span><img alt="Company Logo" src="company_logo.gif"><input type="file" accept="image/*"></span>
    </header>
    <article>
        <h1>Recipient</h1>
        <address contenteditable>
            <p>Recipient Company</p>
        </address>
        <table class="meta">
            <tr>
                <th><span>Invoice #</span></th>
                <td><span contenteditable>2015-09</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Date</span></th>
                <td><span contenteditable>September 2015</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Commission Payable</span></th>
                <td><span id="prefix">$</span><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="salesheader">
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color:#DBF0BE;"><span contenteditable>Properties Sold</span></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="inventory">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="210px"><span>Property</span></th>
                    <th width="90px"><span>Price</span></th>
                    <th><span>Rate</span></th>
                    <th><span>Gross</span></th>
                    <th><span>Nett</span></th>
                    <th><span>Split</span></th>
                    <th><span>Settled</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable>Add Property Address</span></td>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td><span contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>&nbsp;</span</td>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>&nbsp;</span</td>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>&nbsp;</span</td>
                    <td><span contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a class="add">+</a>
        <Br>
        <table class="salesheader">
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color:#F3D0DC;"><span contenteditable>Costs</span></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="costs">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="210px"><span>Property</span></th>
                    <th width="90px"><span>Type</span></th>
                    <th><span>Size</span></th>
                    <th><span>Qty</span></th>
                    <th><span>Nett</span></th>
                    <th><span>Cost</span></th>
                    <th><span>Date</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable>Add Cost</span></td>
                    <td><span contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td><span contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td><span contenteditable>&nbsp;</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a class="addcosts">+</a>
        <table class="balance">
            <tr>
                <th><span>Total Sales</span></th>
                <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Total Costs</span></th>
                <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Commission Payable</span></th>
                <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </article>
    <aside>
        <div contenteditable>
            <p>Thank you.</p>
        </div>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: without any HTML, it's hard to see if there is a table with the class including 'costs' - and all the associated spans and stuff the code relies on

Comment: Yeah, please show your HTML code.

Comment: A fiddle would be better.

Comment: I have now added the HTML to the post, thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable (`costs`) that is not defined/initialized anywhere. So when you get to this part of the code:

```
// set costs total
cells[5].innerHTML = costs;
```

You get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: costs is not defined

After you define and initialize the variable `costs`, the rest of the code seems to be working fine.

For example, I initialized it to zero along with the rest of the variables (although maybe you want to use a different value), then I didn't get any error, and the code executed completely updating all numbers:

```
var total = 0;
var totalcosts = 0;
var cells, price, total, totalcosts, a, i;
var costs = 0;
```

---

Note: I created my own version of the functions `parseFloatHTML()` and `parsePrice()`. If the code still does not work after defining `costs`, you should check the JavaScript console to see if there is any error going on in any of those two.

Comment: As a recommendation: use the JavaScript console (you can open it with F12 in most browsers). This type of errors is easy to catch that way.

Comment: Hi, I tried this however once I set 'var costs = 0;' then the cost section of the "new cost" row is unchangeable from $0 then. The same method has been used in the first "sold" table by stating 'cells[5].innerHTML = split50;' then making the total += split50, where split50 is not defined anywhere prior either, however this one works? I tried the javascript console and got no errors though...

Comment: It's not the same case as `split50` because you give it a value right before you use it: `split50 = parseFloatHTML(cells[4]) / 2;` (and it gets defined as a global variable). You don't assign any value to `costs` and then use it in an assignment.

Comment: Create a [small working demo](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share the link, I will take a look to check if I see something else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated, you can view the page here: jarahproperty.comoj.com  the only part which isn't working properly is the costs $ amount isn't editable now that var cost = 0; and that tallied amount (of all new costs added) needs to be totaled under "total costs", then that amount deducted from "total sales" to form the total payable...

Comment: What should be the value of `costs`? should it be contenteditable (if you add new ones, the cost is not contenteditable)?

Comment: Costs should be contenteditable in the table row to allow for numerous costs to be added, however the totalcosts tally at the bottom shouldn't be editable, rather just calculate the total of all costs added.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, I have solved the problem myself. Cheers.